# Batik Rasterizer logo watermark remove from genereated image

Tags: java, svg, watermark, batik

Anyone know how to remove the Batik logo from the generated images? I'm trying the examples on their page http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/tools/rasterizer.html

This is the source svg image https://bitbucket.org/llythiumn/cmput206/src/912d7681375d/batik-1.7/samples/barChart.svg?at=Ian2

This is the Java line I'm running to convert the svg to a png image
***java -jar batik-rasterizer.jar -m image/png  samples/barChart.svg***

And this is what the generated image looks like with the logo at the bottom 
http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/xmlgraphics/batik/tags/batik-1_0beta2/test-references/samples/barChart.png

Perhaps its simple but I just can't find the option to remove it. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The watermark is **in** the [source image](https://bitbucket.org/llythiumn/cmput206/raw/912d7681375d97150bb8bb96c945539f8ca49bc8/batik-1.7/samples/barChart.svg). If you don't supply a source image with a watermark you won't get one in the output.

Comment: In the version that i have (batik-1.7\samples) it doesn't show up when I open it in the browser (Chrome, Safari).

Comment: Sure it does, if you use one that supports external `<use>` references.

Comment: Well, I'm getting different results for different browsers depending if I'm opening the svg locally or directly from this link. [link] (http://design.medeek.com/calculator/batik-1.7/samples/)

For me, safari never displays the watermark in both local and direct URL. 

But at least I now know the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found it. I guess I should have tested it with svg files other than the ones batik provided. It seems that the Batik SVG examples come with a tag that forces the logo watermark. But it only does it when generating the image. Opening the svg image in a browser doesn't show the logo.

I tried it with other svg files from here and it worked fine. [http://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files](http://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/)

Comment: I see the logo when I open the image in Firefox. It's an external file so if you're using Chrome or Safari then they don't yet implement external use references.